# Error 1064 (4200) - when I type in a GRANT ALL request in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
GRANT ALL ON uesrName.* TO username@hostname.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-services.co
m' at line 1

Can someone tell me , Is it the " - " is causing my request to fail.

I have used the correct User name and host name provided by pythonanwhere.com
I am using pythonanywhere.coms GUI when performing this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Several objects within GRANT statements are subject to quoting, although quoting is optional in many cases: Account, database, table, column, and routine names. For example, if a user_name or host_name value in an account name is legal as an unquoted identifier, you need not quote it. *However, quotation marks are necessary to specify a user_name string containing special characters (**such as -**), or a host_name string containing special characters or wildcard characters (such as %); for example, 'test-user'@'%.com'. Quote the user name and host name separately.*

You have to quote hostname as

```
username@'hostname.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com'
```

without quote:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON uesrName.* TO username@hostname.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-services.com' at line 1
```

with quote:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON uesrName.* TO username@'hostname.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks Haifeng Zhang
I guess it worked , 

mysql> GRANT ALL ON databasename.* TO stringName@'stringName.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'stringName'@'%' to database 'EndaKeane$rockford911'

Comment: @Enda no problem:) please check it as the answer. The check mark is on the left side of my answer

Comment: I just need to figure out why my acces is denied now.

Comment: @Enda read more about the `GRANT` command from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html   it would help